# Grey-box bug on slide bar when programmatically adding slides in PowerPoint

Tags: c#, powerpoint

I am replacing Slides in a PowerPoint presentation through C#. My method is to instantiate an object of the existing slide, then Slide.delete(). I then InsertFromFile() from another PowerPoint file.

This works well, but the slide preview box of the slide I have added appears grey (instead of providing a preview!). This quickly changes to the proper preview when I click anywhere in the presentation or slide bar; unfortunately, it is not solved by selecting the slide programmatically.

Any suggestions?